# What is the meaning of this numbers in type data of char?

Tags: c, validation, char

```
printf ("Select your choice : );
scanf("%c%c", &choice, &choice2);
if((choice == 49 || choice == 50 || choice == 51) && choice2== '\n'){
...
```

What the meaning for that numbers, for type data of char?
Thx

Comment: `49` is the ASCII code for `1`. I'd rather see `if (choice == '1')` than what you posted. It's clearer for humans, exactly the same for compilers (and will work in strange implementations (like EBCDIC ... or Klingon)).

Comment: You question is a good example why you should never do this. If you are dealing with character values, use the related character literal. Only use numbers if you are dealing with numerical values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your system is using ASCII code (or character code that is compatible with that like UTF-8), 49 stands for "1", 50 stands for "2", and 51 stands for "3".

For other numbers, this should be useful:

[Ascii Table - ASCII character codes and html, octal, hex and decimal chart conversion](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

These numbers are ASCII codes. 49 is 31 hex which is '1'. 50 is 32 hex which is '2' and so on.
Here you can read about [ASCII on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this numbers mean the corresponding numbers in code ascii for the integers 1,2,3.and the '\n' means a new line .